# OptaWeb Vehicle Routing on Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: optaplanner

I just want to ask if OptaWeb Vehicle Routing can be fully functional in Windows subsystem for Linux? I tried to run it but most of the functionalities like the Demo is not working. Hopefully someone can answer this. Thank you!

I tried to run it in Windows subsystem for Linux. It actually run in the localhost, but most of the functionalities does not work.

Answer (score 0):

We are aware that OptaWeb is currently broken. It is unrelated to WSL, it is equally broken on Windows and Linux. I suggest to check out the considerably simplified [OptaPlanner Vehicle Routing Quickstart](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing) instead.